# Does anything auto deactivate LVM2 volumes

Tags: debian, lvm

I have a daemon that creates and destroys LVM2 volumes (using lvcreate and lvremove).  Between creating and destroying the volume it expects a device node to be present in

```
/dev/<volumegroup>/<volumename>
```

However,for some reason every few weeks, something somewhere appears to randomly deactivate one of these volumes.  Does anybody know what might be doing this?

My platform is Debian 7 amd64.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Did you try vgmknodes?

```
vgmknodes  [-d|--debug]  [-h|--help]  [--refresh]  [-v|--verbose] [[VolumeGroupName | LogicalVolumePath]...]
```

It will check the LVM2 special files in /dev that are needed for active logical volumes and creates any missing ones and removes unused ones.

```
vgchange -ay VolumeGroupName
```

If vgmknodes couldn't create device node for you, it makes VG be available to kernel.